# Accessing a control within a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sitecore

Lets say I have the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repSubItems" runat="server" DataSource="<%# SubItems %>" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" 
            FieldName="BlurbSpot_Content_SubHeading" 
            runat="server" 
            Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" />  
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to in code behind be able to do:

```
FieldRenderer1.Style["Width"] = MyCoolWidth;
```

But within the `Repeater` I cannot access the `FieldRenderer1` control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to handle the `ItemDataBound` event of the `repSubItems` repeater. Example:

```
protected void repSubItems_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var fieldRenderer1 = e.Item.FindControl("FieldRenderer1") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer;
        if (fieldRenderer1 != null)
        {
            fieldRenderer1.Style["Width"] = MyCoolWidth;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: +1. You also need to register `repSubItems_ItemDataBound` to the repeater itself.

Comment: `OnDataBinding` for the control is a much better way for doing this.  No reliance on `FindControl` or naming and your code is scoped to the control so you can move it around however you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the row your are looking for specifically in the `Repeater` and then find the control.  Here is an example that can do it for all items in your `Repeater`:

```
// repeater item
foreach (Control cr in repSubItems.Controls)
{
    // assuming this is your templated control name and not the final output name
    FieldRenderer founcControl = cr.FindControl("FieldRenderer1") as FieldRenderer;

    founcControl .Style["Width"] = MyCoolWidth;
}
```

The **better way** to do this would be to implement the `OnDataBinding` for your control specifically because then you have no searching to do:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer1" FieldName="BlurbSpot_Content_SubHeading"
    runat="server" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>"
     OnDataBinding="FieldRenderer1_DataBinding" />

protected void FieldRenderer1_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FieldRenderer rend = (FieldRenderer)(sender);

    // you can do whatever you want to rend at this point and it is scoped to ONLY
    // the control so you never have to search for it.
    rend.Style["Width"] = MyCoolWidth;  
}
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of the features of `OnDataBinding` -- thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Mark Ursino this is the best approach but for some reason it is rarely used.  I think early on in the ASP.NET inception all the examples revolved around `ItemDataBound` so it got really easy to search and find even though there has been a much better way included since the start.